# How to set/change scripting language/api in freeswitch to handle calls

Tags: javascript, lua, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am using freeswitch as telephony/pbx software to handle voip calls (incoming or outgoing).
I have a gui installed (named fusionpbx) for my existing project. The fusionpbx uses lua api to handle calls and events. One possible reason may be following statement by freeswitch official website.

> Lua is the preferred scripting language for custom applications based
>   on FreeSWITCH

But I am more comfortable in JavaScript (or PHP) and fortunately there are JavaScript APIs already available and provided by freeswitch but the problem is, I dont know what is minimal script to setup and load JavaScript API to execute my scripts in javascript (rather than lua).

Answer (score 0):

You create a dialplan and in it set
condition
application: destination_number   data:   ^555$

action
application: javascript  data: yourscript.js

Put your yourscript.js in the scripts directory.

Scripts Directory

Package install
/usr/share/freeswitch/scripts

Source install
/usr/local/freeswitch/scripts

Make sure its readable by FreeSWITCH

Call the dialplan at 555 and it will run your javascript file.